# Can someone point me to the documentation for `redirect_to @model`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my generated controller I'm seeing:

```
 format.html { redirect_to @foo, notice: 'Foo was successfully created.' }
```

What I'm not seeing anywhere is a description of what redirect_to is doing when it is passed a model.

I know what `redirect_to` does.  But how is this particular form different from, say, `redirect_to url_for_foo` or `redirect_to action: :show`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirect_to` uses [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) to generate the path where the client is redirected.

When a model is passed to `url_for`, it tries to compose the corresponding resource URL based on the instance. See for example

```
<%= url_for(@workshop) %>
# calls @workshop.to_param which by default returns the id
# => /workshops/5
```

Same applies to `action: "show"`, once again the url is the result of the computation of `url_for`. You can see more details in the `url_for` documentation I linked above.

Comment: So, basically, we're saying, "redirect this to whatever routes.rb says is the canonical way of rending the record"?  Confusing but useful, then.

Comment: Yes, correct. Personally I don't like it either as it makes very hard to maintain the application in the long run and perform search/replaces of route. I generally always use the explicit path.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html :
 redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
Link

Redirects the browser to the target specified in options. This parameter can be any one of:

- Hash - The URL will be generated by calling url_for with the options.
- Record - The URL will be generated by calling url_for with the options, which will reference a named URL for that record.

Have a look on url_for documenation at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for. As stated there:

Passing a record (like an Active Record) instead of a hash as the options parameter will trigger the named route for that record. The lookup will happen on the name of the class. So passing a Workshop object will attempt to use the workshop_path route. If you have a nested route, such as admin_workshop_path you’ll have to call that explicitly (it’s impossible for url_for to guess that route).

Example:

```
<%= url_for(@workshop) %>
# calls @workshop.to_param which by default returns the id
# => /workshops/5
```